# Should I avoid learning related words at the same time in SRS, and if so, how do I avoid it with Anki?

Tags: vocabulary, anki, spaced-repetition

One anti-pattern discussed in "Fluent Forever" is learning a group of words from a certain theme all at once, such as colours one week, family members another week, and so on.

Does this apply to spaced repetition systems as well?

If so, how do I avoid it? Do I somehow forbid certain cards from showing up on the same day, or do I just have the first day I start learning each card differ? If the latter, is there some easy way to set this up at the time that I enter the cards into the system, so that I do the complicated work in one go, and only have to worry about the act of memorisation on subsequent days?

Related: [This answer](https://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/a/2641/113) to "What are Anki's disadvantages?", which talks about tying related cards, and burying of related cards.

Comment: Is the focus of this question on how to avoid learning related words "together" in an SRS or on evidence whether learning related words together is a bad thing? If it's the former, it is still possible to post a question about the latter (especially one that asks for evidence from studies).